# Can someone recognize any two addresses (generated by hardware wallet) come from the same hardware wallet/mnemonic seed?

Tags: wallet, privacy, seed

Can someone recognize any two addresses (generated by hardware wallet) come from the same hardware wallet/mnemonic seed?If I generate multiple cryptocurrency accounts/addresses in ledger live,is it possible for someone to recognize it comes from the same hardware wallet/seed? I would also want to ask the same question for software wallet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no link between your addresses alone (someone would need your seed, xprv, or xpub for that) you do leave some residual identity once you start spending.

For example if your wallet builds a transaction where two or more of your previously unassociated addresses are used as inputs in the same transaction, then it may suggest that the spender owns both (or more) of those addresses.

Wallet technologies exist that attempt to muddy the waters of those trying to surveil by combining multiple unrelated coin owners to sign a single transaction together with multiple inputs. Basically disproving the assumption that multiple addresses as inputs in the same transactions means one owner owns all the inputs.

Comment: " if your wallet builds a transaction where two or more of your previously unassociated addresses are used as inputs in the same transaction, then it may suggest that the spender owns both (or more) of those addresses" Could you provide specific example where two or more addresses can be used as inputs in the same transaction? I can only think of smart contract as the only case that could happen. Is it true that right now only smart contract is the only possible way to have two or more inputs in one transaction?

Comment: By "disproving assumption", you mean they try to make that assumption wrong in this particular case of  the attempt to "muddying the waters"? Is there successful attempt of the wallet technology you can cite as an example?

Comment: Multiple inputs from different addresses in a single transaction is very common and has nothing to do with smart contracts.

Comment: is there any specific simple application interface to do a transaction with multiple inputs( multiple different coin owners)?